# Pythonic conditional sum on member

Tags: python

I am trying to find a more pythonic way of doing this conditional sum:

```
...
for i in xrange(len(eventVqts)-2, 0, -1):
   events[eventVqts[i].TimeStamp] = total(eventVqts, sourceVqts, i)
   mins[eventVqts[i].TimeStamp] = minx(eventVqts, sourceVqts, i)
   maxs[eventVqts[i].TimeStamp] = maxx(eventVqts, sourceVqts, i)
   avgs[eventVqts[i].TimeStamp] = avgx(eventVqts, sourceVqts, i)
   sums[eventVqts[i].TimeStamp] = sumx(eventVqts, sourceVqts, i)
   times[eventVqts[i].TimeStamp] = eventVqts[i + 1].TimeStamp
   durations[eventVqts[i].TimeStamp] = (eventVqts[i+1].TimeStamp - eventVqts[i].TimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds
...

def total(events, source, index):
   start = events[index].TimeStamp
   end = events[index+1].TimeStamp
   filtered = [s.Variant.Double for s in source if s.TimeStamp >= start and s.TimeStamp < end]
   if len(filtered) > 0:
      return filtered[-1] - filtered[0]
   else:
      Log.Error('No filtered records found')
      return 0

def minx(events, source, index):
   start = events[index].TimeStamp
   end = events[index+1].TimeStamp
   filtered = [s.Variant.Double for s in source if s.TimeStamp >= start and s.TimeStamp < end]
   if len(filtered) > 0:
      return min(filtered)
   else:
      return 0

def maxx(events, source, index):
   start = events[index].TimeStamp
   end = events[index+1].TimeStamp
   filtered = [s.Variant.Double for s in source if s.TimeStamp >= start and s.TimeStamp < end]
   if len(filtered) > 0:
      return max(filtered)
   else:
      return 0

def avgx(events, source, index):
   start = events[index].TimeStamp
   end = events[index+1].TimeStamp
   filtered = [s.Variant.Double for s in source if s.TimeStamp >= start and s.TimeStamp < end]
   if len(filtered) > 0:
      return sum(filtered) / float(len(filtered))
   else:
      return 0

def sumx(events, source, index):
   start = events[index].TimeStamp
   end = events[index+1].TimeStamp
   filtered = [s.Variant.Double for s in source if s.TimeStamp >= start and s.TimeStamp < end]
   if len(filtered) > 0:
      return sum(filtered)
   else:
      return 0
```

So, reverse iterate, starting at 2nd to the last, and grab the aggregations of the source data relative to the event data. Don't get the first value's aggregations.

events{} and source{} are both dictionaries of a .NET type which looks like:

```
.Variant 
.TimeStamp
```

The .Variant structure is pretty much the old VB Variant type.

For each event in events, I want to find all the values in the sources that are >= the timestamp of the event, and < the timestamp of the next event.

My verbose code above works, but it seems to lack a certain elegance I associate with python, like I am working too hard to do this.

NOTE: this is en embedded IronPython environment, so I can't import numpy or any other modules. I only have the IP2.6 runtime to work with. Also, I can't pop in a .NET assembly, so my code has to work as a script. I posted this here, as I did not see that it was IronPython specific, other than the environment. I can deploy a script (as a string property of an object in the model), but not an assembly. All I have is straight text code to work with.

I broke out the start and end variables because it seemed the comprehension syntax did not appreciate embedded square brackets.

How bad is it? Is there a way to do this using a generator? They would all filter the same, so if I could return an object with

```
.min
.max
.sum
.total
.avg
```

That would make me very happy. Especially if it got rid of redundant code.

Comment: It might sound silly but did you consider the obvious refactoring of putting the logic to create `filtered` into its own function?

Comment: Is `source` ordered? You seem to be expecting the results of the list comprehension to be in a particular order in `totalx`.

Comment: @5gon12eder yes, thank you. I saw that opportunity once I got back into my code.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, both the source and eventVqts are ordered.

Comment: You call them dictionaries, though, and neither Python dicts nor .NET Dictionaries provide ordering guarantees. (I think .NET Dictionaries currently iterate in something like insertion order, but this is an implementation detail and not a guarantee.)

Comment: @user2357112 that is true. the code that generates the objects creates them in the proper order before they get to my code. It seems the only objects that are dependent upon order are the eventVqts, as they assume ascending timestamps. They ARE created by a .NET assembly, and inserted in ascending timestamp order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider wrapping the whole thing in an object that knows how to filter itself.

```
class EventInterface(list):
    # pass in the `source` list
    def filter(event, index):  # returns a generator
        start = event[index].TimeStamp
        end = event[index+1].TimeStamp
        return (s for s in self if start <= s.TimeStamp < end)

sources = EventInterface(sourceVqts)

for i in range(len(eventVqts)-2, 0, -1):
    filtered = map(attrgetter('Variant.Double'), sources.filter(eventVqts, i))
```

Then you can do what you like with the results.

```
def avg(sources):
    return float(sum(sources)) / len(sources)

def total(sources):
    return sources[-1] - sources[0]

for i in range(len(eventVqts)-2, 0, -1):
    filtered = map(attrgetter('Variant.Double'), sources.filter(eventQvts, i))
    the_sum = sum(filtered)
    the_avg = avg(filtered)
    the_total = total(filtered)
    # etc....
```

Comment: I accepted your solution, as I will be using it. I have a need to have multiple 'source' data aggregated against the same event time fenceposts, and following your solution is much easier to maintain. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ok, facepalm. Perhaps I was trying too hard. If I do this:

```
for i in xrange(len(event_vqts)-2, 0, -1):
   start = event_vqts[i].TimeStamp
   end = event_vqts[i + 1].TimeStamp
   times[start] = end
   durations[start] = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds / float(1000)      
   filtered = [s.Variant.Double for s in source_vqts if s.TimeStamp >= start and s.TimeStamp < end]
   count = len(filtered)
   if count > 0:
      total = float(filtered[-1] - filtered[0])
      if total < 0:
         total = float((filtered[-1] + rollover) - filtered[0])
      totals[start] = total
      counts[start] = count
      mins[start] = min(filtered)
      maxs[start] = max(filtered)
      avgs[start] = sum(filtered) / float(count)
      sums[start] = sum(filtered)
      stds[start] = std(filtered)
      starting_values[start] = filtered[0]
      ending_values[start] = filtered[-1]
   else:
      totals[start] = 0
      counts[start] = 0
      mins[start] = 0
      maxs[start] = 0
      avgs[start] = 0
      sums[start] = 0
      stds[start] = 0
      starting_values[start] = 0
      ending_values[start] = 0
```

it appears to meet my needs.

Although now I do wonder if a generator would be more performant for larger sets? I will be researching @adam-smith's solution, as it looks very clean.